# Rails - ActiveRecord - associating a combination of elements to a specific ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through

I have an interesting problem that I never had to deal with before. I'm looking for the best way to approach it.

I'm creating an admin site linking students to virtual machines. A Student can sign up for multiple courses and has one virtual_machine_id which depends on the combination of courses they take. An Admin can create new courses and (separately) map combinations of courses to specific virtual_machine_ids.

1) What's the best way to associate a combination of variable elements with a specific id? If the elements were fixed, I would create a table with columns for each element and one column for the virtual_machine_id. But since these elements can change (as admins add or remove courses), how do I map them in a way that I can easily query for a combination and it's associated id?

2) Right now, I have Students mapped to Courses using a has_many :through association and a third table with student_id and course_id. Is this the right way if I need to collect combinations of courses and assign the entire combination a single virtual_machine_id (i can't assign the id to the student because they could potentially have more than one virtual_machine depending on how many courses they take)

I was looking at the EAV (entity-attribute-value) model as a solution but the general consensus seems to be that it's a bad a idea because you lose some ActiveRecord features.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use **EAV** with **ActiveRecord ORM** you can look at [hydra_attribute gem](https://github.com/kostyantyn/hydra_attribute) which allows to create new attributes in runtime and has possibility to find/sort/group by them.

Currently the **0.3.2** version doesn't support **attribute sets** but in the next release I'll add this feature and you will be able to assign the unique attribute collection to each **Student** record.